# How to print or get JRE version of an application running on a server?

Tags: java

I mean using javacode I want to find the JRE version of application but not server.
In my production server I am having thousands of applications in java like tomcat,websphere,axway etc. I want to know particular application jre version.I will write a class and I want print using that. That class will be placed in particular application.

I tried [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222187/how-to-check-jre-version-prior-to-launch) but I didn't get it.

Comment: This answer is what you're looking for I think: http://stackoverflow.com/a/222868/180100

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/222868/57695 from the question you linked to.  What do you mean by "I didn't get it"?

Comment: @RC. no that prints JRE version of main server(rd-hat).Which has many servers tomcat4,5,6 if I run a application in tomcat 4, its related jre versi0n should be printed.

Answer (score 8):

You should try `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));`
I have successfully tested that it prints the actual version of Java that is used to run the code.